# Accurate Sleep for Java on Windows

Tags: java, windows, sleep

Does anyone know a Library which provides a Thread.sleep() for Java which has an error not higher than 1-2 Millisecond?

I tried a mixture of Sleep, error measurement and BusyWait but I don't get this reliable on different windows machines.

It can be a native implementation if the implementation is available for Linux and MacOS too.

**EDIT**
The link Nick provided ( http://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks ) is a really good resource to understand the issues all kinds of timers/sleeps/clocks java has.

Comment: I don't stick to Thread.sleep() ... I just want to stop execution of my Program for a certain amount of ms (1-20). If there is another way to suspend AND wake up my code frequently and accurate don't hesitate to point towards another solution.

Comment: Sleep should be accurate enough for an animation so long as it's Java 1.5 or later.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To improve granularity of sleep you can try the following from this [Thread.sleep](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml) page.

> **Bugs with Thread.sleep() under Windows**
>
> If timing is crucial to your
> application, then an inelegant but
> practical way to get round these bugs
> is to leave a daemon thread running
> throughout the duration of your
> application that simply sleeps for a
> large prime number of milliseconds
> (Long.MAX_VALUE will do). This way,
> the interrupt period will be set once
> per invocation of your application,
> minimising the effect on the system
> clock, and setting the sleep
> granularity to 1ms even where the
> default interrupt period isn't 15ms.

The page also mentions that it causes a system-wide change to Windows which may cause the user's clock to run fast due to this [bug](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=821893).

**EDIT**

More information about this is available
[here](http://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks) and an associated [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6435126) from Sun.

Comment: This helped a lot. I ran tests on 2 different windows machines with different load and got a average error of 0.8ms. On a Linux I had an average error of 0.3ms - Thanx you saved my day :-)

Comment: Great, it is a shame it is a hack - I currently use similar but am yet to find an equally functional and elegant solution for Swing animation. If anyone is more enlightened....

Comment: Does any of this still apply in later windows OSes such as Windows 10 or 11?

Answer (score 12):

This is ~5 months late but might be useful for people reading this question. I found that `java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos()` does the same as `Thread.sleep()` but with nanosecond precision (in theory), and much better precision than `Thread.sleep()` in practice. This depends of course on the Java Runtime you're using, so YMMV.

Have a look: [LockSupport.parkNanos](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#parkNanos(long))

(I verified this on Sun's 1.6.0_16-b01 VM for Linux)

Comment: I tried this just now and it won't park for less than 1 ms, which is the same as Thread.sleep. :(

Comment: Depends on your OS.  On Linux with > 2.6 kernel, it will.

Comment: Genius! Finally a way to rest me wary thr'ead. I've never been a fan of any of the java alternatives to this. This is so clean..

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, as of Java 6 all java sleep-related methods on Windows OS [including LockSupport.awaitNanos()] are based on milliseconds, as mentioned by several people above.

One way of counting precise interval is a "spin-yield". Method System.nanoTime() gives you fairly precise relative time counter. Cost of this call depends on your hardware and lies somewhere 2000-50 nanos.

Here is suggested alternative to Thread.sleep():

```
   public static void sleepNanos (long nanoDuration) throws InterruptedException {
        final long end = System.nanoTime() + nanoDuration;
        long timeLeft = nanoDuration;
        do {
            if (timeLeft > SLEEP_PRECISION)
                Thread.sleep (1);
            else
                if (timeLeft > SPIN_YIELD_PRECISION)
                    Thread.yield();

            timeLeft = end - System.nanoTime();
        } while (timeLeft > 0);
    }
```

This approach has one drawback - during last 2-3 milliseconds of the wait hit CPU core. Note that sleep()/yield() will share with other threads/processes. If you are willing to compromise a little of CPU this gives you [very accurate sleep](http://andy-malakov.blogspot.com/2010/06/alternative-to-threadsleep.html).

Comment: Good post. However compromising CPU is not a very good solution (true, depends on your use case)

Comment: How do you calculate SPIN_YIELD_PRECISION? Is it just 1 ms?

Comment: `SLEEP_PRECISION = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(2);` `SPIN_YIELD_PRECISION = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(2);` Give good results, however I didn't run these on production servers

Answer (score 4):

There are no good reasons to use `Thread.sleep()` in normal code - it is (almost) always an indication of a bad design. Most important is, that there is no gurantee that the thread will continue execution after the specified time, because the semantics of `Thread.sleep()` is just to stop execution for a given time, but not to continue immedeately after that period elapsed.

So, while I do not know what you try to achieve, I am quite sure you should use a timer instead.

Comment: Im playing with diffrent kinds of Gameloops and as i dont want to waste all the CPU after logic and rendering are done (there isnt too much to draw and calculate in a Tetris clone) i need a method to suspend my Program.
But because I didn't want to start a discussion about how GameLoops are Designed I created a question about how I can suspend my code for a specific amount of time.

Comment: @haBaLeS Generally I would consider using something like a CyclicBarrier if I am at all understanding where you are coming from.

Answer (score 4):

JDK offers the Timer class.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Reading the docs clearly indicates that beyond the plumbing to make this a generalized framework, it uses nothing more sophisticated than a call to Object.wait(timeout):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)

So, you can probably cut the chase an just use Object#wait yourself.

Beyond those considerations, the fact remains that JVM can not guarantee time accuracy across platforms.  (Read the docs on [http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29))

I think you'll need to experiment with a compromise solution combining Timer and busy polling if you want to want the highest timing precision possible on your platform.  Effectively Object#wait(1) -> System#nanoTime -> calculate delta -> [loop if necessary].

If you are willing to roll your own, JNI pretty much leaves it wide open for platform specific solutions.  I am blissfully un-aware of Window's internals, but obviously if the host OS does provide sufficiently accurate realtime timer services, the barebones structure of setting up a timerRequest(timedelta, callback) native library shouldn't be beyond reach.

Answer (score 3):

The Long.MAX_VALUE hack is the working solution.

I tried Object.wait(int milis) to replace Thread.sleep,  but found that  Object.wait is as accurate as Thread.sleep (10ms under Windows). Without the hack, both methods are not suitable for any animation

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the `Thread::join` [overrides](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long,%20int)) on the current thread. You specify the number of milliseconds (and nanoseconds) to wait.

Comment: So if I'm wrong, please point out why instead of just silently voting down, thanks

Comment: The nano-second are rounded to the milli-second for wait and join.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an implementation of [real-time Java](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the new concurrency libraries.  Something like:

```
private static final BlockingQueue SLEEPER = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1);
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        SLEEPER.poll(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Sleep %5.1f%n", time/1e6);
    }
}
```

This sleeps between 2.6 and 2.8 milliseconds.

Comment: You mean, "This sleeps between 2.6 and 2.8 _milliseconds_"?

Comment: Thank you, Joao. I do most of my timings in micro-seconds and I get them confused some times. :-/

Comment: I'm seeing result a bit more random with this method, while the trick of Any Malakov seems to have a more precision. Yet I agree that the spin yield may have to be chosen carefully