# Java make thread start simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

I got a code here, when it runs it creats and starts a new thread that prints a word per sec, after 5 sec the main method stops the thread. So the program will print 5 words and it does....but not on my homecomputer only on my laptop. On my home computer it prints 6 times, why?

```
public class Main {
  public static void main (String [] args){
    try {
      T1 t1 = new T1();
      System.out.println("Creating and staring thread 1\n");
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      t1.stopThread();
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
  }
}

public class T1 extends Thread{

  private boolean alive = true;

  public T1(){
    start();
  }

  public void run(){
    while(alive){
      try {
        System.out.println("Tråd T1: Tråd 1");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
    }
  }
  public void stopThread(){
    alive = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are lucky that your program stops printing at all.  You have a program that has undefined behavior and it could run forever on some machines.  You must make `alive` `volatile`, otherwise there is no guarantee that your secondary thread will ever see the change made to `alive` in the main thread.

Look at the end of the Java language specification [chapter on memory](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.9); they basically give your example as something that must not be done.

That being said, you might still get 6 printed lines instead of 5 from the inaccuracy of `Thread.sleep`.

Answer (score 9):

Both results are correct. Sleep times are approximate.

Comment: Take a look at those to get a better understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824110/accurate-sleep-for-java-on-windows - http://www.javatuning.com/why-is-thread-sleep-inherently-inaccurate/