# What's the accuracy of java.net.Socket.connect timeouts?

Tags: java, sockets

I was wondering what's the timeout accuracy of the method [java.net.Socket.connect(SocketAddress, int timeout)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29)?

Initially I'd thought that it's built atop [java.lang.Object.wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long,%20int%29) and thus have a 10-15 millisecond error ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/824110/632951)),

But after examining the source code, it looks like all it does is to delegate the call to [java.net.SocketImpl.connect(SocketaAddress, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketImpl.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29).

Does this mean that java.net.Socket.connect(SocketAddress, int) does not use Object.wait and hence is not subject to the 10-15 millisecond error Object.wait has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it looks like all it does is to delegate the call to java.net.SocketImpl.connect(SocketaAddress, int).

which is an abstract method of the `SocketImpl` class.

The subclass actually implementing it (the system-default `SocketImpl` implicitly retrieved from `SocketImplFactory.createSocketImpl()` in the `Socket` constructor) in turn relies on a native method, so it's not possible to know the inaccuracy in a platform-independent way.

-- EDIT (response to comment)

If not using a `Socket` subclass that specifies a custom `SocketImpl` via the protected `Socket(SocketImpl impl)`  constructor, the standard `Socket` instance created by the `Socket()` constructor uses a `SocksSocketImpl` (which in turn extends `PlainSocketImpl`).

`SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocketAddress address, int timeout)`

calls

`super.connect(SocketAddress address, int timeout)` (`PlainSocketImpl.connect(SocketAddress address, int timeout)`),

which in turn calls

`PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(InetAddress address, int port, int timeout)`,

which in turn calls

`PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(InetAddress address, int port, int timeout)`,

which in turn calls

`PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(InetAddress address, int port, int timeout)`,

which is a private **native** method, and we don't know what's inside :)

So no, we're **not** relying upon `Object.wait`.

--

See http://jcs.mobile-utopia.com/jcs/18846_PlainSocketImpl.java and http://jcs.mobile-utopia.com/jcs/31401_SocksSocketImpl.java for source code

Comment: I couldn't browse the source after SocketImpl. Do you happen to have the source code of the implementations?

Comment: I thoroughly edited my original answer in response to your comment. Please have a look

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would expect that the socket connect timeout is handled directly by the OS/kernel. The C socket API supports connect timeouts, so I expect the JVM native implementation will simply delegate to it.

Secondly, why do you care about accuracy of 10-15ms on a network connect? It sounds like you'll end up with something very brittle.

Comment: No I was wondering if java.net.Socket.connect uses timing based on Object.wait  or some *internal* functions.

Comment: @Pacerier The answer to "Why do you care...?" would probably help responders give you the answer your looking for. You'll also have to define 'internal'. Delegating to the native OS socket implementation is what I would consider to be 'internal'.