# Spring Web Service - Web Service Communication

Tags: java, web-services, synchronization

Today I have kind of theoretical question (I just can't find a way to write a sample code).

My system architecture looks like this: `Client <--> Web Service1 <--> query <--> Web Service2 <--> Server`.

I cannot change it because my company needs it to be separate.

Problem lies in synchronization when `client` sends a request to `WebService1`, `WS1` puts an object in query,  `WS2` is watching the query all the time and check if there is something new, if it is it sends a request to `Server` which processes the request and gives a proper response which has to come back to `Client`.

The `Server` does not have an equal time of process for all requests.  I have to get request from Client and send a request within one session. `Thread.sleep` or any kind of a method that stop executing code is unacceptable.

Can anyone give me a hint what should i use?

Comment: I do not understand it all at. What do you mean by WS2 is watching the query? Is WS2 a Web Service or a process? Your system architecture does't fit with your description of the process.

Comment: ok, i am sorry, just have edited the architecture. Querry is intependent thing, WS2 is webservice Actually i can't say more about WS2 because i am not the one who is responsible for it, i am just creating a WebService1 which put request on querry and wait for the response

Comment: So, Client sends a request to Server1, via WS1. WS1 puts an objects in a query and wait (checking if there is any thing new). Then, we we have a process running on Server2, checking new objects. When there is a new object, it call Server via WS2. Some job are done, WS2 replay, process one Server2 put something back on the queue, then, the process running on Server1 detects the change, does some job and replay to the client. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's forget about communication between the queue and the server.

1. The client send a request to the server 1 via WS1 (synchronous com.)
2. Process in server 1 writes in a queue.
3. Process in server 1 waits an answer from the queue. At this point, I am afraid, since communication with client is synchronous, the client should wait. How? `Thread.sleep` is a solution.

How much the client should wait? It depends on:

- Frequency process in server 2 read the queue
- Time that take to server 1 call server via WS2
- Time that take to server to process the request.
- Frequency process in server 1 read the queue looking for an answer from server 2

So, you can use a loop:

1. ask the queue for the answer
2. If answer is there, nice, you respond to the client. If not, thread must wait. The loop starts again.

But, you can not do the client to wait too much, you you can do something like:

1. That the time waiting exceed the maximal time? If yes, break the loop and answer to the client that something was wrong.
2. ask the queue for the answer
3. If answer is there, nice, you respond to the client. If not, thread must wait. The loop starts again.

I think you should reconsider stopping the code execution, since there is no code to execute until you have answer from the queue. Anyway, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9143719/980472) to thread sleep alternatives.