# How to make a Timer?

Tags: java, timer

I want to make a `Timer` that waits 400 MSc and then goes and prints "hi !" (e.g.). I know how to do that via `javax.swing.Timer`

```
    ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       System.out.println("hi!");
    }
};
```

plus :

```
    timer = new Timer(0, action);
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.setInitialDelay(400);
    timer.start();
```

but as I know this definitely is not a good way as this kind of `Timer` is for Swing works. how to do that in it's correct way?  (without using `Thread.sleep()`)

Comment: There is also `java.util.Timer`

Comment: I don't know how to use that?

Comment: What do you want to do in the end? Maybe using a job framework would be a better solution for you depending on what you need to do with it.

Comment: you are true but at the end I just want to run a `Runnable`, doesn't need any complex work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hi!");

            }
        }, 400);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider Quartz scheduler, it's a really scalable, easy to learn and to configure solution. You can have a look at the tutorials on the official site.
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/quick-start

Comment: why not using util.Timer ?

Comment: It depends on what you have to do. If you need a complex condition involving the date, the time of the day and so on, it's better to use Quartz because it has a scheduler with great flexibility. You can establish conditions like every Wednesday of the month or every last day of the month at 12.00. It also give the possibility to repeat automatically a job more than once for example one per hour for 5 hours. On the other hand, for a simple timer, I'd use util.Timer too.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class currentTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(150L);`

is an alternative;

You could also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143719/java-alternative-to-thread-sleep) Question

Which suggests using a `while` loop which just waits
or a  [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: @Soheil thx for that info ;)
I'm new to Java, learned sth again =)