# Accurate timing in java

Tags: java, time

How can I achieve accurate timing in Java? I know Thread.sleep() is inaccurate and leads to InterruptedExceptions. I'm trying to make a physics simulator and I want to have accurate code.
Here is my code so far:

```
public class FreeFall() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double height = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double xi = height;
        int counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            height = xi + 9.8 / * counter * counter;
            System.out.println(height);
            counter++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this be in Java8+?

Comment: A good place to start is the Java8 tutorial about the relevant classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html

Comment: please post code which compiles :)

Comment: Your code doesn’t compile. `... 9.8 / * ...`

Comment: You’ve also blown your physics.  You want (1/2)*a*t^2 ... unless you wanted your object to fall under two gravities.  I mean “rise” at 2 gravities ... your gravity should be negative, too.

Comment: This is probably a helpful resource for you: [How to calculate time and distance from acceleration and velocity](http://www.dummies.com/education/science/physics/how-to-calculate-time-and-distance-from-acceleration-and-velocity/) Your `height` should be (`.5*9.8*elapsedSeconds*elapsedSeconds`) (well, you should subtract that from your original height)

Comment: `InterruptedExceptions` only occurs if some other thread interrupts the sleeping thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

Conventional implementations of Java are not [real-time systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing). So **you cannot count on deterministic performance**.

If you insist on deterministic timing, seek out an implementation of [real-time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java).

Similar Question: [*Java - alternative to thread.sleep*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9143719/642706)

## `Thread.sleep`

You can *ask* for sleeping with a resolution of nanoseconds, but you may not get it due to limitations of current computer hardware. See [the other `sleep` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-int-) taking a second argument for nanoseconds.

```
Thread.sleep( 0L , 300L ) ;  // Ask to sleep 300 nanoseconds.
```

The behavior of `Thread.sleep` is never deterministically reliable, as discussed below. Many factors such as internal CPU scheduling (such as out-of-order execution and hyper-threading), OS scheduling of the JVM, the JVM’s scheduling of threads, and occasional garbage collection all impact the actual execution timing. So you can never count on predictable execution unless you move to a [real-time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java) implementation.

## `System.nanoTime`

To track elapsed time, call [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--). This has a resolution of nanoseconds, but not likely precision. As of 2018, conventional computer hardware clocks are only accurate to a range of around microseconds, not nanoseconds. This is good for things such a micro-benchmarking (tip: [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)). The `System.nanoTime` has *nothing* to do with telling the current date-time. The number returned is a count from some undocumented origin moment (in my experience, since the JVM launched, but not guaranteed). The 64-bit number may overrun in a few decades of continual running.

```
long start = System.nanoTime() ; // Just some progressively incrementing number of nanoseconds. NOT the current date-time.
long stop = System.nanoTime() ;
long elapsed = ( stop - start ) ;  // Calculate elapsed time in a resolution as fine as nanoseconds (though not likely precise beyond microseconds).
```

## `Instant`

To get the current moment in UTC with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. In Java 8, the current moment could captured only to milliseconds, but in Java 9 and later a [fresh implementation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730) of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) may deliver finer resolution. I am seeing [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) captured in Oracle JDK 9.0.4 on macOS Sierra.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds though likely with precision not as fine.
```

> 2018-03-16T01:18:54.898583Z

## `Duration`

I suggest generally using the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) objects as-is. You can compare via [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#isBefore-java.time.Instant-), `isAfter`, and `equals` methods. To calculate elapsed time, use [`Duration.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration d = Duration.between( instantThen , Instant.now() ) ;  // A span of time not attached to the timeline, with a resolution of nanoseconds.
```

## Avoid `System.currentTimeMillis​()`

As for [`System.currentTimeMillis​()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--), you can forget about this method. You are better off using `Instant` instead.

## Executor

As for [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and `TimerTask`, you should know that those classes are now legacy, supplanted by the more sophisticated *Executor* framework added to Java 5 and later. See [the Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

## Real-time Java

Even with Executors, you cannot expect exact split-second accuracy in execution. The host OS controls scheduling the JVM, and its performance may vary. Within the JVM, threads are scheduled dynamically, and their performance may vary. In particular, garbage collection may impact performance at particular moments.

If you want deterministic timing of execution, you need to obtain an implementation of [real-time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java). The conventional implementations of Java such as the Oracle JDK and OpenJDK are most certainly *not* [real-time systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to make use of timestamps, taking advantage of [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--), which will give you elapsed milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970.

Take a timestamp when your object starts to fall. Then, within your loop, you can take a timestamp representing the current time. Subtract `startTime` from `currentTime` and you get an accurate number of milliseconds. From this, for example you can calculate how far your object should have fallen over that period of time given a constant speed.

The nice thing about this approach is that it doesn't matter whether you're running on a fast or slow processor, since your timestamps reflect the actual passage of time vs. the number of iterations of your loop.

Comment: Actually, you may get better results in Java 9 and later by calling `Instant.now()` for results in microseconds as I am getting with the Oracle Java 9.0.4 on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8 and above -
You can use  java.time library
It has date time classes

**For Date -**

```
  //To create a new date
LocalDate ld =  LocalDate.Of(2018,March,26);
   //To print current date
LocalDate.now();
```

**For Time -**

```
 //To create a new time
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.Of(11,22);
   //To print current time
Local time.now();
```

**For both Date and Time -**

```
   //To create a new date time
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.Of(2018,March,26,11,22);
   //To print current date time
LocalDateTime.now();
```

**Note : Please take care of these things -** 
-These classes are only available in Java 8 and above.
-These classes has private constructor, so you can't instantiate them
-Of is a static method and hence called using class name
-These classes are immutable, and hence any update you need to create is to saved into a new object

Comment: What does this have this have to do with the Question? A `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment, and does not represent a point on the time line. So it is irrelevant to the Question about accurately tracking time. Ditto for `LocalTime`. And `LocalDate` is date-only, so much too gross a granularity for the time-tracking indicated in the Question.

Comment: Correct me, LocalTime give time in nanoseconds. One can subtract both the time to get elapsed time, precision up to nanoseconds

Comment: `LocalTime` is limited to a single generic 24-hour clock, with no concept of date or time zone. So that class does not account for anomalies such as Daylight Saving a Time (DST). Your results will fail on the DST cut-over. Your results will fail after midnight. The class you are looking for is `Instant`, a point on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds and an accuracy of around microseconds depending on the host computer’s hardware clock.