# Add a decimal millisecond delay to Java code

Tags: java, multithreading, events, timeout, timedelay

I want to add a delay of 0.488 ms to my java code. but thread.sleep() and Timer functions only allow a granularity of millisecond. How do I specify a delay amount below that level ?

Comment: Check the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824110/accurate-sleep-for-java-on-windows

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since 1.5 you can use this nice method `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(long timeout)`:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(1000000);
TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1000000000);
```

Comment: You can't rely on this if you want to wait small number of microseconds.  The only way to do this is to busy wait on a thread.

Comment: These functions are defined as calling `Thead.sleep(long millis, int nanos);`, which in all versions of OpenJDK as of yet end up calling Thread.sleep(long millis)` with nanos rounded to the nearest millis.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Thread.sleep(long millis, int nanos)`

Note that you cannot guarantee how precise the sleep will be. Depending on your system, the timer might only be precise to 10ms or so.

Comment: In WIndows JDK1.6.0_37, this method just add one millisecond, and call Thread.sleep(). It is fully ignoring nanos time.

Comment: @kornero: That's exactly why you cannot guarantee the precision of this method :) Nevertheless, on some systems you can get sub-millisecond precision.

Comment: Not for any version of openjdk. If there's a JDK that implements this I haven't seen it. <https://github.com/openjdk/jdk18/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#L322-L338>

Answer (score 3):

TimeUnit.anything.sleep() call Thread.sleep() and Thread.sleep() **rounded** to milliseconds,
all sleep() unusable for less than millisecond accuracy

Thread.sleep(long millis, int nanos) implementation:

```
public static void sleep(long millis, int nanos) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
{
  ms = millis;
  if(ms<0) {
    // exception "timeout value is negative"
    return;
  }
  ns = nanos;
  if(ns>0) {
    if(ns>(int) 999999) {
      // exception "nanosecond timeout value out of range"
      return;
    }
  }
  else {
    // exception "nanosecond timeout value out of range"
    return;
  }
  if(ns<500000) {
    if(ns!=0) {
      if(ms==0) { // if zero ms and non-zero ns thread sleep 1ms
        ms++;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    ms++;
  }
  sleep(ms);
  return;
}
```

same situation is with method wait(long, int);