# How to use method Object.wait(long timeout, int nanos)

Tags: java

I am reading about class `Object` and I found a method `wait(long timeout, int nanos)`.

I read a description [Docs Oracle Class Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long,%20int%29) and I found that:

> The amount of real time, measured in nanoseconds, is given by:
>
> ```
> 1000000*timeout+nanos
> ```
>
> **Parameters:**
> *timeout* - the maximum time to wait in milliseconds.
> *nanos* - additional time, in nanoseconds range 0-999999.

I took a look at implementation of this method (`openjdk-7u40-fcs-src-b43-26_aug_2013`) and I found this piece of code:

```
public final void wait(long timeout, int nanos) throws InterruptedException {
    if (timeout < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (nanos < 0 || nanos > 999999) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "nanosecond timeout value out of range");
    }

    if (nanos >= 500000 || (nanos != 0 && timeout == 0)) {
        timeout++;
    }

    wait(timeout);
}
```

First and second `if`s are obvious. Third one does nothing or just increments `timeout` and does not care about `nanos`.

My question is, how I can invoke method `wait(long timeout, int nanos)` which really works with given `nanos`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use a different virtual machine. If you check other vm sources, you'll eventually find one which has that wait implemented in native code. You will need a os with nano timer suport as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *does* take into account nanos: the third `if` says that:

```
if (nanos >= 500000...
    timeout++;
```

which means that if we have more than 500000 nanos we'll round it up to another millisecond, otherwise, we'll round it down.

That's also compliant with the definition: `1000000*timeout+nanos` after converting it back to milliseconds.

Comment: Let's say, I would like to wait for `3000 milis` and `500005 nanos` = `3000 500005 nanos`. I run method with params `wait(3000, 500005)`. `500005 > 500000`, so it goes inside `if` and does `timeout++` and method `wait(3001)` will be invoked. In my opinion it is not the same, I did not want `wait(3000)` or `wait(3001)` what I wanted was `wait(3000, 500005)`

Comment: @ruhungry I understand that it's not what you wanted, but that's the way the developers of JDK implemented it. Further, due to os events like scheduler-events and context-switch - you are not guaranteed to get an exact wait time even in millis let along nanos

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#parkNanos%28long%29

Also many answers to this question may help:

[Accurate Sleep for Java on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824110/accurate-sleep-for-java-on-windows)